# App icon is not shown on https://portal.office.com/account/#apps

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have set app icon on https://portal.azure.com => app registration => my app => branding.
Icon is visible on https://www.office.com/apps, but is not visible on https://portal.office.com/account/#apps. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it does indeed change both icons—but there is a delay.

When you change the icon in the Azure Active Directory Enterprise App settings, it shows almost immediately in that portal, but it can take a couple of hours to show up in the Office portal. It also shows up in `portal.office.com/account/#apps`, but it seems the delay for that one is even longer; I've seen up to fie hours delay.

This is likely because there are different sync processes in the background to make copies of your icon to various Azure services. You can tell by getting the URLs of the icons from the various pages by using the browser developer tools to see where it's grabbing the images from.

Sometimes you may have to upload the image again, and you can try to change multiple parameters just for good measure while you're at it. For example, change the name slightly at the same time as uploading the icon, and just be patient. Also, it could help to clear the cache on your browser or use incognito mode.

Comment: That's a good finding regarding the different URLs on different servers. I'd have expected these all to come from the same central server, and for it just be a matter of updating the reference. Obviously, you'd expect some potential delays due to caching, but I wouldn't have otherwise expected it to copy the images out to different locations. Interesting.